# Can I report malicious ip addresses for money?

Tags: security, ddos, anti-virus, malware, attacks

My servers get attacks from thousands of ip addresses everyday. I have an idea. Can I report those malicious ip addresses, or use the resource to earn some money?  How?

You may think these attacks are common on the Internet. But the attacks to my servers are kind of special. They come from thousands of different ips everyday. They try to login my box(but fail). The most uncommon thing is every ip just does several attempts then other ips continue. If this continues, I think I can catch quite a lot of compromised computers in the world.

Do not limit your thoughts to reporting those ips to somewhere. This is definitely a good resource to make some money in a way not known to me yet.

The down-votes have made it impossible for me to ask new questions here. Can you visitors kindly up-vote this question to help me get rid of the restriction? I curse those down voters.

Thanks!

Comment: If this was possible every SysAdmin would be very rich. Just install fail2ban and move on

Comment: Not only sysadmins. My 40$ Odroid server at home logs failed authentication attempts like crazy when I open port 22 in my router.

Comment: Are those security/antivirus companies interested in the data?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing special about the pattern of attacks you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer - no.
Setting a honeypot server to collect such IPs is easy and cheap and the information quickly becomes stale. Most of the scans come from short lived cloud/vps servers.

Cloud providers like Microsoft an Amazon see millions of such IPs and they are in a much better position to collect and use such information

Answer (score 2):

There's nowhere you can get paid for reporting IP addresses.

The nearest thing would be to set up your own blacklist (similar to something like Spamhaus) using software like rbldnsd, and serve the list of IP addresses from there.  Then, charge people to access your blacklist (or, charge them to get off of it, like some do).

This would be problematic since you'd need to provide a robust and reliable service, deal with attacks (both cyber and legal) from entities on the list, and of course find people willing to pay for something they can get largely free from elsewhere.